# Understanding error handling in ASP .NET (WebForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, error-handling, webforms

I have a Web Form (.NET 4.0) web application built as:

MyApp.Portal (Main portal with the pages, WCF AJAX services, scripts etc.)

MyApp.BusinessLayer (Class library call DataAccess to get data)

MyApp.Services (Class library contains WCF server for server side code)

MyApp.DataAccess (ADO Oracle)

I am trying to following some tutorials on error handling but so far I am getting inconsistent results.

My question is how should I be handling errors in my app?
Should I be wrapping all methods in try/catch?
Should I just wrap the methods in the business layer with the try/catch?
How would I handle errors that occur in the PortalLayer with the WCF Ajax methods?

For example I added the following to my Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
            Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

            if (exc is HttpUnhandledException)
            {
                if (exc.InnerException != null)
                {
                    exc = new Exception(exc.InnerException.Message);
                    Server.Transfer(@"\Pages\Error.aspx?handler=Application_Error%20-%20Global.asax", true);
                }
            }

        }
```

However most of the time this isnt getting called. I just see error an error message show on the screen (Like a glorified alert).
 Or if this method is called then exc is not HttpUnhandledException so the transfer never takes place.

I also tried this in my web.config but I don't see that this does anything. (If I comment it out I get the same results)

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx?handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx?msg=404&amp;handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config"/>
</customErrors>
```

The ultimate goal is to redirect the user to a page (or maybe just nicely display the error) while out the same time either log it in a file or write the error out to a database.

Comment: Application_Error does not get called for 404's, as this happens before the application is even run.  In fact, if you think about it, that would make sense.  How can it run a handler if it can't even find the application to run?  Additionally, the web server itself handles many kinds of Http errors, and you have to tell the server how to handle them.

Comment: Your question is really broad. and no answer will be perfect or correct for this. Yes, you can "not handle" exception anywhere and only in your UI layer but this is detrimental in the long run. Generally, there are 2 types of exception. Execution exception and business exception. Execution exception is something happened at runtime. business exception is, when you do something related to your business and you got to condition when, lets say, you can't have more orders than a product - you throw exception. then you handle each. For bus. exception - you describe why you can't continue.

Comment: For runtime exception you just say "unexpected error" but you log all info in Event log, for example. I like when UI talks to BLL in a request-response manner. UI sends request - fetch order detains for order 25. BLL sends response - here is data and success flag and error message if success !=true. This way, all UI has to do, either show message or fill data. And it can intercept its local UI exceptions. And if you have this sort of communication, you can change UI anytime. have multiple UI clients, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` will get called for exceptions that happen in the main thread when server is processing pages (request to .aspx,.ashx resource).

It won't get called in two scenarios:

- you're firing new thread when processing .aspx resource & the exception will happen in that new thread
- in web service methods, wcf methods, etc. (i.e. non-.aspx resource)
- exception is "bad ass" exception - the kind that corrupts application domain - `StackOverflowException` or `OutOfMemoryException`

So for WCF, WebServices it makes sense to wrap all entry points in

```
try {} 
catch(Exception e) {
  Logger.Log(e);
  throw;
}
```

statement (note if you have lot of those, invest your time in more generic solution).

Also note - if there is an error on your error page you'll get yellow screen of death (obviously). So I prefer showing static html pages as error page (lowest probability that something will go wrong).

In your error handling code you're not cleaning up the error state, also I'd prefer `Redirect` to `Server.Transfer` for error handling. Final snipped looks like:

```
 var ex = Server.GetLastError();
 Logger.Log(ex);
 Server.ClearError();
 Response.Redirect("/error.aspx");
```

Final note - no need to do error logging by yourself (good programmers are lazy - in terms of "don't reinvent the wheel) - there are plenty of great logging modules like Elmah, Microsoft Enterprise Library or log4net.

Comment: I implemented log4net and that works niec, however in the case of the WCF service if I error and throw the message I would like to display that on a custom error page.  Right now it just throws it to the screen. (I do not see the YSOD)  Would I have to redirect in each of the catch statements?

Comment: For unhandled WCF exceptions, a nice way to deal with them is to implement a WCF global exception handler - i.e. implement your own IErrorHandler and register it in the web.config as a behaviour.  Likewise, for Web API register your own System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler. This way you don't need to wrap every method in try/catch.